# mysqli_real_escape_string() returns empty string in server

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
                $cser = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","karmsys") or die("server connection failed:".mysql_error());
                if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                    $name = $_POST["name"];
                    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"]);
                    $clientPic = mysqli_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d-H-i-s")) . ".jpg";
                    $image_tmp = $_FILES['clientPic']['tmp_name'];
                    $confirm = "No";
                    echo "Name: " . $name . "<br>Comment: " . $comment . "<br>Pic: " . $clientPic ;
                    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/client/$clientPic");
                    $query="insert into review values (
                          null,'".$name."',
                          '".$comment."',
            '".$confirm."',
            '".$clientPic."'
                      )";
                    $result = $cser->query($query);
                    if($result > 0){
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                              <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                              <strong>Success!</strong> We got your comment. Wait till verify
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                              <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                              <strong>AWW!</strong> Something gone wrong. Try Again
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
        ?>
```

this is my code. I searched in google that mysqli_real_escape_string not working in server and got only one result that make a connection before real_escape, i did it but still it working on localhost but not in server

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping some of the user inputs at all. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations. You're also using it wrong. If you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), you can see that the first argument should be the db connection.

Comment: Dont use mysqli_real_escape_string as a prevention for sql injection. Its really bad practice. You should try use prepared statements instead: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: `mysql_error()` <-- That's not going to work with a MySQLi connection.

Comment: Also, replace `if (isset($_POST["submit"]))` with `if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]))` and make sure you close that if-statement with an `else { echo "The POST request headers didn't contain any data in the first place!"; }`